# iCloud-CoreData resolve conflicts

Tags: core-data, ios8, icloud, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm using Ulysses application for iPad. This app uses iCloud as a sync system. In case of conflicts the app shows a popover with the descriptions of the devices involved.

In particular:

- Name of the device (e.g. Matteo's Macbook Pro)
- Time stamps (e.g. 22nd March 2015 9:34)

Choosing the right version of the note it's than possible to complete the synchronization.

I've already setup the icloud stack to handle the synchronization, and it works pretty good but i can't figure out how, in case of conflicts, retrieve that kind of informations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is too broad. You need to demonstrate a minimum of research and then ask the community when you get stuck.

Comment: I've already setup the icloud stack to handle the synchronization, and it works pretty good but i can't figure out how, in case of conflicts, retrieve that kind of informations (device name, timestamp). Thanks

Comment: OK, you should mention that in your question. Did you try to create a conflict and see what happens?

Comment: It automatically manages conflicts with the default policy. It calls the callback associated with event "NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification". 
In the callback, as a parameter, i have a NSNotification* but it doesn't have that infos...

PS: thanks for the suggestions you gave about my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` and rather than just calling `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`, first examine the two versions.

This can be done by retrieving the `userInfo` dictionary of the notification which should contain the `NSManagedObjectID`s of the changed objects under the `NSUpdatedObjectsKey`.

Comment: Yes, true.
Infact printing description of userInfo i get:
{
    deleted = "{(\n)}";
    inserted = "{(\n)}";
    updated = "{(\n    0xd00000002004007c <x-coredata://927F1FC4-7773-453B-9C5B-46484DCF60CE/CDActionPad/p2049>\n)}";
}

But how can i retrieve informations about the devices involved in the conflicts and timestamps of the changes for both devices?